# Sync-ing two table, update the value and insert the row that is not exists

Tags: sql, oracle, synchronization

I am having problem on syncing two table. so i have these 2 tables,

TABLE TESTA

```
NAME  VALUE1 VALUE2 VALUE3 SOURCEVAL RESULT
HEAD1      1      0      0        50    100
HEAD2      0      1      0        50     50
HEAD3      0      0      1        50    200
```

TABLE TESTB

```
NAME      V1     V2     V3 SOURCEVAL RESULT
HEAD1     10     99     99        99     99
HEAD5     99     99     99        99     99
HEAD6     20     99     99        99     99
```

What I am aiming to do is to sync these two table and store them in TESTB, 
The desired result is something like this,

TABLE TESTB

```
NAME      V1     V2     V3 SOURCEVAL RESULT
HEAD1      1      0      0        50    100
HEAD2      0      1      0        50     50
HEAD3      0      0      1        50    200
HEAD5     99     99     99        99     99
HEAD6     20     99     99        99     99
```

And my SQL is like this,

```
UPDATE t2 SET t2.v1 = t1.value1 and t2.v2 = t1.value2 and t2.v3 = t1.value3 and t2.sourceval = t1.sourceval and t2.result = t1.result FROM testb AS t2 INNER JOIN testa AS t1 ON t2.name = t1.name
```

What am I doing wrong here ?? anybody can suggest me a better solution ?

Comment: read about `merge` operator in oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following approach using [MERGE](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/merge-statement.php)

**Merge Statement**

```
MERGE INTO TESTB trg
     USING TESTA src
        ON (trg.CNAME = src.CNAME)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
   UPDATE SET trg.V1 = src.VALUE1,
              trg.V2 = src.VALUE2,
              trg.V3 = src.VALUE3,
              trg.SOURCEVAL = src.SOURCEVAL,
              trg.RESULT = src.RESULT
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN
   INSERT     (trg.CNAME,
               trg.V1,
               trg.V2,
               trg.V3,
               trg.SOURCEVAL,
               trg.RESULT)
       VALUES (src.CNAME,
               src.VALUE1,
               src.VALUE2,
               src.VALUE3,
               src.SOURCEVAL,
               src.RESULT);
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a82ddc/1)

```
CREATE TABLE TESTA
(
   CNAME       VARCHAR2 (16),
   VALUE1      NUMBER,
   VALUE2      NUMBER,
   VALUE3      NUMBER,
   SOURCEVAL   NUMBER,
   RESULT      NUMBER
);


CREATE TABLE TESTB
(
   CNAME       VARCHAR2 (16),
   V1          NUMBER,
   V2          NUMBER,
   V3          NUMBER,
   SOURCEVAL   NUMBER,
   RESULT      NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO TESTA (CNAME,
                   VALUE1,
                   VALUE2,
                   VALUE3,
                   SOURCEVAL,
                   RESULT)
     VALUES ('HEAD1',
             1,
             0,
             0,
             50,
             100);
INSERT INTO TESTA (CNAME,
                   VALUE1,
                   VALUE2,
                   VALUE3,
                   SOURCEVAL,
                   RESULT)
     VALUES ('HEAD2',
             0,
             1,
             0,
             50,
             50);
INSERT INTO TESTA (CNAME,
                   VALUE1,
                   VALUE2,
                   VALUE3,
                   SOURCEVAL,
                   RESULT)
     VALUES ('HEAD3',
             0,
             0,
             1,
             50,
             200);
INSERT INTO TESTB (CNAME,
                   V1,
                   V2,
                   V3,
                   SOURCEVAL,
                   RESULT)
     VALUES ('HEAD5',
             99,
             99,
             99,
             99,
             99);    
INSERT INTO TESTB (CNAME,
                   V1,
                   V2,
                   V3,
                   SOURCEVAL,
                   RESULT)
     VALUES ('HEAD6',
             20,
             99,
             99,
             99,
             99);
```